# How to set cover of playing song in Safari for Now playing widget?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, safari-extension, mediasession

I trying to set metadata in injected script on music website like this

```
var updateMediaSessionMetadata = function() {
    if (!navigator.mediaSession)
        return;
    var coverPath = trackInfo["coverPath"];
    var cover = { src: coverPath, sies: "256x256", type: "image/jpeg" }
    var metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: trackInfo["name"],
    artist: trackInfo["artists"],
    album: trackInfo["album"],
artwork: [ cover
//        { src: coverPath.replace("400x400", "80x80"), sizes: "80x80", type: "image/*" },
//        { src: coverPath.replace("400x400", "100x100"), sizes: "100x100", type: "image/*" },
//        { src: coverPath.replace("400x400", "200x200"), sizes: "200x200", type: "image/*" },
//        { src: coverPath.replace("400x400", "300x300"), sizes: "300x300", type: "image/*" },
//        { src: coverPath.replace("400x400", "400x400"), sizes: "400x400", type: "image/*" }
    ]
});
```

As you can see i try different image size. But unfortunately the cover in Now Playing widget doesn‘t appear. How to fix that? Note that `title`, `artist` and `album` set as appropriate. Link `coverPath` is correct.

[image]

Enviroment macOS Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400) Safari 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12)